# Selecting records based on start and end datetime fields

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2010

I am using delphi 2010 and Firebird (locally) for testing, but eventually will be running my app against MS Sql Server or Oracle.

If I have datetime fields (start_time & end_time), and i want to select all records from the last 30 days, or a rangle of dates, how do i do this, taking into consideration the three databases mentioned above (firebird, sql server, oracle)

The example datetime fields look as such:  10/15/2012 9:20:49 AM

The following is an example sql statement which i would like to add an additional where clause to:

```
  SQL.Text:= 
      'SELECT J.id, MIN(p.start_Time) as startTime, MAX(p.end_Time) as endTime, ' 
      +  'SUM(p.duration) as TotalDuration ' 
      + 'FROM phases p ' 
      + 'JOIN jobs j ON j.id = p.jobs_Id ' 
      + 'WHERE j.id=:jobId ' 
      + 'GROUP BY j.id';
```

1. How do I select all records from phases where starttime or endtime is within the last 30 days?
2. How do I select all records from a phases where starttime or endtime fall within a range of dates
   (lets say for example, i am using the params :beginDateRange  & :endDateRange)

thanx for your help

Comment: won't it work just like with integer ?  `(column_date < :endDateRange) and (column_date >= :beginDateRange)` ? and for "last 30" you only have to set beginRange and omit condition of endRange

Comment: Also for "last 30" u can use `datediff (day from current_date to cast(? as date))` - though it probably is Firebird-only construct: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-datediff.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns (start_time and end_time) are declared as the appropriate date types for the respective DB, you should be able to simply set the parameters with the AsDateTime function.

```
Query1.ParamByName('start_time').AsDateTime := Date-30
Query1.ParamByName('end_time').AsDateTime := Date;
```

This should work across the different databases - eg if they're declared as timestamp in Firebird and Date in Oracle.  Depending how you structure your query, you could then use the same SQL statement and just set the start_time and end_times as required by your result set.  Depending on what you actually want to retrieve back, the following should return the last 30 days worth of records based on start_time.

eg:

```
SQL.Text:= 
      'SELECT J.id, MIN(p.start_Time) as startTime, MAX(p.end_Time) as endTime, ' 
      +  'SUM(p.duration) as TotalDuration ' 
      + 'FROM phases p ' 
      + 'JOIN jobs j ON j.id = p.jobs_Id ' 
      + 'WHERE j.id=:jobId '
      + '  and Trunc(p.start_time) >= :beginDateRange and Trunc(p.start_time) <= :endDateRange '
      + 'GROUP BY j.id';
ParamByName('beginDateRange').AsDateTime := Date - 30;
ParamByName('endDateRange').AsDateTime := Date;
```

Firebird and Oracle will handle the *between* syntax but not sure about SQL Server (but presumably it does).  In which case you could change the *and* clause to something like:

```
and Trunc(p.start_time) between :beginDateRange and :endDateRange
```

Comment: u seemed missing the word: between date1 AND date2.  See http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=select

Comment: I am getting a "conversion error from string - 10-25-2012"  and i am not sure why, since my datetime fields are in the "10/25/2012 9:20:49 AM" format. Could it be the Date function?

Comment: I i change it to the following : ParamByName('beginDateRange').AsString := formatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy',Date - 30).....i get the error "conversion error from string - 10/25/2012"

Comment: This is still not solved, as your answer does not seem to work. see my errors in my comment above

Comment: @JakeSnake please post your DDL for the table phases.  Need to know the data type you have allocated for the start_time and end_time fields. Are they DateTime or VarChar or what... As I've seen on another question you've asked, what you see as your date representation in your favourite DB Explorer (eg IBXpert, IBConsole etc) does not necessarily dictate how the value is stored in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database is sorted according to the date and time, then you can run a loop to find the first entry where the date is more than 31. then you know you can loop from that fields index number upwards....cut out the first loop by using adotable. Add the sql in the while loop when it retrieves all the data.

while not adotable.BOF   do

........
there is alot of other ways and much better ways especial if using oracle. 
Only take the concept and logic behind this since adotable wont be

Comment: Rudi, maybe I got you wrong, but aren't you suggesting to sort and fetch all the records from DB to client ? If so, I hope you ever won't do such thing in commercial application :-)

Comment: @TLama for "last 30 days" that may be perfectly valid suggestion, assuming table does not have rows "from the future". However for "between date1 and date2" that is awful, i agree.

Comment: I know the data can be retrieved from the client if retrieved and becomes vulnerble...but as I said if it it sorted then you can only retrieve the fields upto 30 days without ever touching any other field...run the sql in the loop once sorted then you can only retrieve the relevant data. If you sort your fields, use parameters , and don't store the retrieved data in a client set it will be safe

Comment: I just saw the second part of the question after the 30 days not the inbetween.... Sorry my mistake